# I am not able to route to a template from the first "/". How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

My client side code is

```
Router.configure({layoutTemplate:'layout',loadingTemplate:'loading'});

    Router.route('/thread/:_id',{
name: 'individualthread',
template: 'individualthread',
  waitOn:function(){
  return Meteor.subscribe('forumQuotes',this.params._id)
  },
data: function(){
  var currentThreadRoute=this.params._id;
  return forumQuotesList.findOne({_id:currentThreadRoute});
  }
});

  Router.route('MyHome',{name: 'myHome'});
```

So when I click on an individual thread, it goes to the thread and the url becomes suppose "localhost:3000/thread/5v6pJSuxvsJyhAA7G".
Then if I click on 'MyHome' href, the  url becomes "localhost:3000/thread/MyHome" and the correct template is not routed to.
I want the url to become "localhost:3000/MyHome".

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanking you all.

Answer (score 1):

Router.route('MyHome',{name: 'myHome'});

You can use ../ before Myhome to solve this.

Router.route('../MyHome',{name: 'myHome'});

I hope that this solve your problem. This is my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to use `pathFor` in your HTML for links. This makes your code much easier to manage as routes change.

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'myHome'}}>MyHome</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably has more to do with how you're rendering your links than your router configuration.

You likely have links that look like this:

```
<a href="MyHome">MyHome</a>
```

Change them to this:

```
<a href="/MyHome">MyHome</a>
```